# Writing a php value into a html input line

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo my php value from mysql database into my html input line but every time i try it either shows blank or breaks the page.  How would i write this in the html line with the exact same format?

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM MICROCHIP_TBL ORDER BY entry_date desc LIMIT 20";
$result = $conn->query($sqli);

if ($result->num_rows > 5) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " " . $row["order_number"]. " " . $row["chip_number"]. "<br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Why do you have `$row[""]`?

Comment: You also need to check if there's a semicolon in your last line (`$conn->close`), or it's just a typo.

Comment: Remove `" . $row[""]. "` from your code.

Comment: You select all (`*`) then you select `order_number` and `chip_number`. Delete the last two and just have `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: i fixed it, sorry, that wasn't supposed to be in there because i took ID out of that line.  I just want order_number and chip_number.  It all shows up fine at the top of the page, works perfect.  I just dont know how to put it in the html input line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your code. Correct those:

1. `SELECT` statement contains extra columns with `*`. **Change it** to:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM ...
   ```
2. <s>No argument supplied for column name: `" . $row[""]. "`. **Remove that**.</s>
3. <s>You haven't terminated the `$conn->close()` statement with a `;`.</s>

   ```
   $conn->close();
   ```

---

If you wanna put something inside an `<input />`, you need to use `value`:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />
```

Comment: you were correct on the first part, i changed that thank you.  the other 2 suggestions was a mistake on my posting, i edited that as well.  I just need to know how to echo the value into my html input line.  thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @chrisbahr "**echo the value into my html input line**" What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: i want the 20 entries that i'm pulling from my database to show in the html box at the bottom of the page instead of at the top where the php line is putting it.  i tried value="<?php echo $row["order_number"]; ?>"  but no luck so far, still blank.  Am i just asking for too much or should i just look into making a table instead?

Comment: Why does the data display fine on the page but when i try to put it in the input line with value=" <?php 'same line from the php' ?>" it just shows a blank in the box?

Comment: I just moved the PHP display down and took the HTML box out and made it look nice with CSS.  Thanks anyways for trying guys.